# Unable to copy .conf in /etc/supervisor/conf.d/ docker file

Tags: docker, ubuntu

I am trying to install supervisor in docker file as follow:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04 
RUN \
  apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y supervisor && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
  sed -i 's/^\(\[supervisord\]\)$/\1\nnodaemon=true/' /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
VOLUME ["/etc/supervisor/conf.d"]
WORKDIR /etc/supervisor/conf.d
EXPOSE 80 443 5002 5005 22
CMD ["supervisord", "-c", "/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf"]
```

It works. But once I add following:

```
COPY AppSupervisor.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/
```

before

```
EXPOSE 80 443 5002 5005 22
```

Then docker image build and docker run are successfull but I am unable to see any conatiner with `docker ps`

Comment: What should the `VOLUME` line do?  (I would delete it; it mostly just has confusing side effects.)  If the container exits (you should see it with `docker ps -a`) does it produce any interesting logs?  Can you split this application up into multiple containers, without using supervisord?

Comment: @DavidMaze I have to use only docker file for a multiple process. Can I create multiple containers from one docker file only?

Comment: You can do that (specify a specific Compose `command:` or put a command after the `docker run image-name`).  It should be straightforward to build multiple images too; even if you have only a single source repository you can `docker build -f Dockerfile.httpd` to have multiple Dockerfiles.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably there might error in supervisor config which leads to exit container.

Better to run the container in foreground `docker run -it --rm my_image` or check container logs you will find something `docker ps -a` and `docker logs container_name`.

for test purpose, Changes that will require to work with below example

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install nginx -y
WORKDIR /etc/supervisor/conf.d
COPY supervisor.conf .
```

Here is the working example that will start Nginx.

```
[program:nginx]
command=nginx -g 'daemon off;'
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
autostart=true
priority=1
autorestart=true
exitcodes=0 , 4
startretries = 20
```

this should work, so correct config file accordingly.

by running container in the foreground you will see

```
2020-07-31 01:15:09,339 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2020-07-31 01:15:09,339 INFO Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisor.conf" during parsing
2020-07-31 01:15:09,347 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
2020-07-31 01:15:09,347 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
2020-07-31 01:15:09,348 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
2020-07-31 01:15:10,351 INFO spawned: 'nginx' with pid 9
2020-07-31 01:15:11,398 INFO success: nginx entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
```